# Deserializing a datetime string without any format manipulation

Tags: c#, json, datetime, datetime-format

I'm receiving a formated datetime variable in a WebAPI controller. On deserialization, I just want to get the string value without any datetime format manipulation.
Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetByDateTime([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
       var parsedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString()); 
        // When I hover on the parsedData during debugging, it's value is
       {{"StartDateTime": "2020-11-03T15:59:00+05:00","EndDateTime": "2020-11-04T15:59:37+05:00"}}

       var StartDateTime = parsedData.StartDateTime;
       var EndDateTime = parsedData.EndDateTime;
      //But at this point values of StartDateTime  and EndDateTime  are 
      "11/03/2020 15:59:00" And "11/04/2020 15:59:37" respectively....
.
.
.
}
```

**How can I get the original values of both variables** i.e., "2020-11-03T15:59:00+05:00" and "2020-11-04T15:59:37+05:00" respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"11/03/2020 15:59:00" is only the display in the debugger. The DateTime variables just contain date and time, no formatting instructions. But you won't be happy if the debugger would display just the raw bits and bytes, so it formats it nicely when you hover over the variable.

To get the original format back, use an appropriate format like `StartDateTime.ToString("O")`

For more info read [the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)